# ¿Cómo ejecutar el evento SelectedIndexChanged en un dropDownList sin recargar la página?

Tags: sql, asp.net

Necesito que al cambiar el objeto del DropDownList se ejecute el método SelectedIndexChanged que me mostrará cierta información en algunos textBox, el problema es que se recarga la página cada vez que se ejecuta, intenté hacerlo con updatePanel pero siempre se manda el primer valor del control y nunca el que selecciono.

```html
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="LIDActInd" runat="server" Font-Names="MAXWELL REGULAR" Font-Size="20px" ForeColor="White" Text="ID del Cliente a Actualizar:"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="CBIDCliente" runat="server" Width="150px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CBIDCliente_SelectedIndexChanged" AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="True">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostbackTrigger ControlID="CBIDCliente" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                <br />
```

Comment: Por curiosidad bro, ¿qué tanto conoces lo que son los controles `asp:UpdatePanel`?

Comment: Bastante poco, a decir verdad.

Comment: Podrías contarnos ¿qué cosas has intentado?

Comment: Siento que estás aprendiendo ASP.net Webforms, por lo que te recomiendo revisar tutoriales aquí: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/index.htm - https://channel9.msdn.com/Search?term=asp.net&lang-en=true Saludos :D

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por el aporte!
De momento, estoy mirando cómo funciona el asp:UpdatePanel, parece ser la única solución.
Cuando lo quito, el evento se ejecuta, pero con el problema de la recarga y de que solo toma el primer valor del dropDownList.

Comment: ¡De nada bro :D ! ¿Para qué tienes esos `triggers`?

Comment: Inicialmente el evento no se estaba ejecutando, así que puse los triggers y si se ejecuta, pero pasan dos cosas:
El dropDownList queda con el primer objeto.
Y a pesar de que se ejecuta el evento, la información que necesito no aparece.

Comment: Ya solucioné el problema de que no mostraba los datos, pero todavía sigue obteniendo únicamente el primer valor del dropDownList.

Comment: ya intentaste ejecutar tu codigo en el **TextChanged** en vez del **SelectedIndexChanged** ??